# Meet-up at the 2013 Esri User Conference?

Tags: discussion

Are there any plans for a meet-up at the 2013 Esri User Conference in San Diego?

I would be very interested in meeting with other GIS.SE folks during the week, but I'm not local so I have no idea where to suggest a meet-up.

(In the absence of a better idea, leave a comment if you're attending the UC, and something will work out)

Comment: I'll be there (of course!) but my time's pretty restricted. If I'm not scheduled for something, I'm hopping off or on the Redlands bus. For a quick, and not too expensive, restaurant, can't beat Tin Fish just across the railroad tracks.

Comment: I'm attending as well, happy to join a meet-up with GIS.SE folks.

Comment: I'm attending too but virtually ;)

Comment: Best thing is to organize something in the gaslamp in the evening. Tweetup is normally sunday evening & thursday evening is the big party. Monday evening in the gaslamp might work well. Dick's Last Resort can be a good spot for something like this. That's where the tweetup normally is.

Comment: Okay, I also I just submitted an idea of a GIS.SE talk at the dev meetup, with the idea of maybe doing some live Q&A (but then people on here have to be ready to read and respond to questions 7:30-8:30 PDT on July 10th).

Comment: How about this - I'm presenting during the Lightning Presentation session on Monday afternoon. Come and say hi afterwards if you're around and we can all head somewhere. It'd be good to meet some people on the first day

Comment: I'm game, and there is no shortage of places in the Gaslamp district.

Comment: The talk on gis.stackexchange.com for the dev meetup on Wed has been greenlighted. I am thinking I will give a brief overview, try to run through some of the features people miss (like meta and review), and get some questions posted for people to answer live? Any other ideas?

Comment: All sounds good; hope to see the folks around...

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the plan then.
Stephen Lead is doing a Lightning Talk on Monday night in Ballroom 20D between 4:30pm and 6pm.
At the end of the lightning talks, we can all meet by the three-wide door in the corner and figure out from there where we are going.

Answer (score 4):

GIS.SE people are also welcome to gather/meet/discuss at [WhereCampSoCal.org](http://WhereCampSoCal.org) -- a free, geospatial unconference at SDSU following the UC.